# Linear combination of basis function in logarithm space. Is it possible?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a function $f(x)$. As theory said that it can represent by linear combination of basis functions such as
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_ig_i(x)$$
where $\alpha$ is coefficient and $g(.)$ is basis function

Assume that if I work in logarithm space such as $h(x)=\log(f(x))$, then Can I represent $h(x)$ as linear combination of basis functions?
$$h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\beta_ig_i(x)$$

This is one example of $f(x)$ and $h(x)=\log(f(x))$. As shown in figure, the variability of $h(x)$ and $f(x)$ look like same. Hence, I think that $h(x)$ also can represent as linear combination of basis functions. Is it true
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's is no reason for that to be true generally speaking, it highly depends of the finite-dimensional functional space $E$ you're talking about. 
It would be true if $E'=\{\log f,\, f\in E\}$ were a linear subspace of $E$. Then you could decompose any element of $E'$ on a basis of $E$.

Comment: I updated my question by adding a example of $f(x)$. As I shown, $h(x)$ also can represent as linear combination of basis functions

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but maybe this observation will help you.

$$
\log\left(\prod g_i^{\beta_i}\right) = \sum \beta_i \log(g_i)
$$

Comment: Thanks, the expected answer that I am looking for that is "Can we represent a logarithm of a function by linear combination of basis function?".